# is there a way to get variables from Power Automate into Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, power-automate, azure-automation, azure-runbook

Hi i'm making an onboarding flow which in Power Automate cloud which will create a user, assign them to a department and add them to a distribution list accodrding to their department and generate aliases based on their email adress.

In order to accomplish this I need to use a Powershell script running in an Azure Automation Runbook since Power Automate does not allow me to assign someone to a distribution list.

I have managed to successfully create a Power Automate flow which creates users, as well as a Powershell script that a user to a distribution list and creates the alias. However I don't know how to "tie these two together". I know i need to use the "Create Job" action for Azure Automate in Power Automate however I don't know how exactly I would get powershell to recognize variables generated by Power Automate.

Comment: Have you looked into creating an Azure Function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do agree with @swathidhanwada, I have reproduced from my end and see this is working fine when I pass `UserPrincipleName` in JSON format.

Below is the flow in my logic app
[image]

Code view of the `Create job` step

```
{
    "inputs": {
        "host": {
            "connection": {
                "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureautomation_1']['connectionId']"
            }
        },
        "method": "put",
        "body": {
            "properties": {
                "parameters": {
                    "UPName": "@{body('Create_user')?['userPrincipalName']}"
                }
            }
        },
        "path": "/subscriptions/@{encodeURIComponent('<SUBSCRIPTIONID>')}/resourceGroups/@{encodeURIComponent('<RESOURCEGROUPNAME>')}/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/@{encodeURIComponent('<AUTOMATIONACCOUNTNAME>')}/jobs",
        "queries": {
            "x-ms-api-version": "2015-10-31",
            "runbookName": "runbook",
            "wait": false
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the script in my runbook

```
Param(
[string] $UPName
) 

Write-Output “$UPName”

Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity <IDENTITY> Member $UPName
```

*Results:*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can Azure Automation connectors which is available for Power Automate Premium Class. For more information refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureautomation/) and [this](https://techwizard.cloud/2020/07/16/power-automate-to-azure-run-book/) document.